# couchDB , python and authentication

Tags: python, couchdb

I have installed couchDB v 0.10.0, and am attempting to talk to it via python from Couch class downloaded from couchDB wiki. Problem is:

```
Create database 'mydb': {'error': 'unauthorized', 'reason': 'You are not a server admin.'}
```

I hand edited the local.ini file to include my standard osx login and password. I now have full access via futon but no joy WRT python. Is this an http header issue?

At a a loss - thanks!

Comment: Which python library are you using? There are several listed on the python wiki page (http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Python)

Comment: thanks andyuk - I am using EXAMPLE code that is on wiki page since it is simplest. I am also trying to find couchDB doc on disabling auth (locally)

Answer (score 23):

To concour David's reply, (i.e. "This is how I do it using module CouchDB 0.8 in python 2.6 with couchdb 1.0.2")

```py
couch = couchdb.Server(couch_server)

couch.resource.credentials = (USERNAME, PASSWORD)
```

Comment: worked for me in a similar situation...once I remembered to put my username and password in quotes!  It's kind of implied in lysdexia's answer here but I mention it here just in case someone else is missing that at the end of a longish day.  Unless of course you have actually defined them elsewhere and are just using variable names here.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that I was able to use this on the library version 1.0, running on debian wheezy against CouchDB 1.6.1, where the admin password was set in local.ini under [admins]. I assume it will work with normal users, too.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do:

```
db = couchdb.Database("http://your.url/yourdb")
db.resource.http.add_credentials(username, password)
```

after which all your requests should work.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a .http property in resource, but there is couch.resource.credentials.  So I did couch.resource.credentials = (SERVER_USER, SERVER_PASSWD) which works for me.

Answer (score 5):

The `Couch` class in the example does not pass any authentication information to the database, so it is not a miracle that it does not allow privileged operations. So your only options are:

- disable authentication completely (as you mentioned)
- pass the user name and password as part of the URI
- pass the user name and password as an `Authorization` HTTP request header

If you want to pass a user name and a password, then you will need to change the `Couch` class. Sending an `Authorization` HTTP request header is easier, since the Couch class uses the `httplib.HTTPConnection` class. You can add such a header next to the `Accept` one this way:

```
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic " + 'username:password'.encode('base64')[:-1]}
```

Same for the other HTTP request methods.

The documentation on the basic authentication is here:

http://books.couchdb.org/relax/reference/security

Comment: Documentation on the security features of CouchDB:

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview

Answer (score 3):

Just pass it as part of the URI...python-couchdb will parse the user/pass out and use them:

http://user:pass@localhost:5984

Comment: This is true for python-couchdb 0.7 and above, so make sure you're up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Above are all nice; but I've found that for oauth validation methods versus basic auth, this works really well:

```
from couchdb import Server, Session
auth = Session()
auth.name = USERNAME
auth.password = PASSWORD
s = Server('http://localhost:5984/', session=auth)
db = s['dbname']
```

Note: This will not work with basic authentication; in such a case, fviktor has what I consider to be the best answer. You might also look into the security reference material he linked to if you're interested in persistent auth sessions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several patches for python-couchdb that enable authentication. The code probably will be included in Version 0.7 but until then you can usr teh fork at http://github.com/mdornseif/couchdb-python - it allows you to use http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:5984/ type URLs.

http://blogs.23.nu/c0re/2009/12/running-a-couchdb-cluster-on-amazon-ec2/ (at the bottom) shows how to use CouchDB passwords.